# CodeIgniter - Quotes in form

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

Let's say in my db it is a field NAME which contains text with single and double quotes:

> TEST1 "TEST2" 'TEST3'

now I want to edit this value in a form with below code:

```
<label for="name">Full name</label>
<?php $test = $data['name']; ?>
<input type="input" name="firma_oficjalnie" value="<?= $data['name'] ?>"/><br />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

The problem is that displayed data not contains single or double quotes.
How to do it properly?

Comment: `type="input"` maybe you were referring to `type="text"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add `htmlspecialchars()` on the variable.

```
<label for="name">Full name</label>
<?php $test = "TEST1 \"TEST2\" 'TEST3'"; ?>
<input type="text" name="firma_oficjalnie" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($test); ?>"/><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Under the hood:

What happens is that it closes the `value` improperly since attribute has quotations inside, thats why the values get cut.

Your markup without function:

```
<input type="text" name="firma_oficjalnie" value="TEST1 " test2"="" 'test3'"="">
```

Comment: Perhaps don't rely on comment above and mention the `type="input"` issue here within your answer.